# My Cat seems to be extremely itchy all the time

Tags: cats, shedding

My cat seems to be extremely itchy all the time, even after we've applied her flea meds. She does get fleas if we don't apply the meds every 3 to 4 weeks, but even when we have she seems to be scratching herself all over the place non-stop.

We've had her at the vet but the vet seems to think her skin is healthy and can't see any other issues.

It is changing into summer at the moment and she's an extremely fluffy cat and during this time of the year she sheds about three quarters of that fluffiness.

Is it possible that the hair loss process agitates her skin?

Comment: It could be a number of things. Also even if she has some fleas it can be driving her mad with itchiness. A flea bomb in the house might be a good idea. However she may have some eczema

Comment: @Yvette a flea bomb? Never heard of it, would any pet store/general store have it and is it safe for children? 
And how would I know if it's eczema, or would only a vet be able to establish that?

Comment: A flea bomb is a product that puts chemicals all through the house to kills fleas. You'd have to check the instructions. Eczema, if the skin has a rash, and yes best to ask a vet. Though even one flea can drive an animal mad and where there's one there will be more. Let us know how you get on